# Properties of Gaussian binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

Given $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+q^kt)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k(k-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}_{q}t^k$$
How do I show that as $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+q^kt)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{k(k-1)/2} \ t^k}{\phi_k(q)}$$ where $\phi_k(q)=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)$

It's give without proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Properties) and in Macdonald's Symmetric Function and Hall Polynomials. Any kind of assistance will be appreciated

Comment: I presume $k=r$?

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad. I conflated the notation on Wikipedia and in the book. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $t^k$-coefficient is
$$q^{k(k-1)/2}\binom nk_q=q^{k(k-1)/2}\frac{(1-q^n)(1-q^{n-1})\cdots(1-q^{n-k+1})}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^k)}.$$
As $n\to\infty$ the numerator tends to $1$, so this tends to
$$\frac{q^{k(k-1)/2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^k)}.$$

Comment: Why does the numerator tend to 1?

Comment: @junkquill In whichever relevant topology you have on the set of power series in $q$, $q^n\to0$ as $qnto\infty$.

Comment: Where did the $j$'s come from?

Comment: How do we know that $q^n \rightarrow 0$, when $n \rightarrow \infty$? I'm still a bit confused

Comment: @junkquill: How do you define convergence on formal power series? The definitions I know all make this obvious.